# Method that accepts any parameter, loop through it for search into DateTime variables, change them and return a new object in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I want to wrote a function where I can pass any kind of parameter (mostly IQueryable or List<>) + local Time Zone ("Central Standard Time" etc).

Function to convert time:

```cs
public DateTime? LocalTimeConvert(string locationTimeZone, DateTime? dateTimeUtc)
{
    var offset = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(locationTimeZone);
    var timeZoneCorrection = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateTimeUtc.Value, offset);
    return timeZoneCorrection;
}
```

I've searched through hundreads of stackoverflow topics but I seems that I have a little lack of C# knowledge.

So far I wrote this:

```cs
public static void LocalTime<T>(T value, string locationTimeZone) 
{
    if(value.GetType().IsGenericType && value.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
    {
        IList<T> collection = (IList<T>)value;
        foreach (var element in collection)
        {
            var properties = element.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                if (property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
                {
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my try to do the part where **T value** will be an `List<>`. Can anyone share with me an article where I can read about how to return the list of the same type as I got? Also after I'll get the properties with `typeof(DateTime)` should I cast property into `DateTime` and then use the `LocalTimeConvert`?

Comment: "change them and return a new object". Do you mean you want to create a new list and add all existing objects to it (so only changing them, but keep in mind if it's a reference type it'll also change the objects in your source list) or do also want to create copies of the objects inside the list and only change and return those copies inside a new list?

Comment: I want to change only DateTime values inside the list I will provide to the method and return the same list as I provided but with changed DateTime values.

Comment: Then there is no need to create and return a new list. Declare your method as `public static T LocalTime<T>(T value, string locationTimeZone)` and then at the end `return value;`.

Comment: But didn't I assign the `value` to a new variable here: `IList<T> collection = (IList<T>)value;` ? And then I'm looping on that new variable?

Comment: No with this you create a new typed reference to the same list in memory by casting the original list to the type you want. In memory there will only be one concrete list, so any changes to that list or to objects in that list will be reflected in all variables that reference said list.

Comment: I would highly recommend reading up on casting and reference types.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like :

```
public IEnumerable<T> LocalTime<T>(IEnumerable<T> value, string locationTimeZone)
```

So you receive a list (no matter which type are the items) and you can return the same list once you finished.

EDIT:
For the DateTime stuff, isn't the DateTimeOffset type something you could use ?